# Extracting the same data from various HTML documents

Tags: html, web-scraping, web-crawler, extract

Let's say I have several HTML pages from unrelated websites, but that contain the same overall information. I want to extract that information in a flexible manner, i.e. I want to only have to write a small number of data extractors for all of the pages (ideally, one). Say the fields are (to use a blog example) `author, date, title, text`. The classes of the HTML tags that denote these could be totally different for each page, but still display on the page in roughly the same way. For example, take [this post](http://www.cnn.com/2013/05/18/us/connecticut-train-derails/index.html?hpt=hp_t1) from CNN and [this post](http://gawker.com/student-fakes-kidnapping-to-distract-his-parents-from-a-508490039) from Gawker. Both contain the same information - the information that I want - somewhere on the page when it is actually displayed. Is there a nice way to extract that data? Writing separate extractors is an option, but not a good one; there are about a thousand styles of documents in the dataset I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do that is by finding a common element in all of those websites (e.g. they share the same DOM structure, or have the same ID, or are preceded by the same content in a previous tag like an `<h1>`).

Otherwise, you need to write different rules or regular expressions for each case.

Unless, of course, you write an algorithm so intelligent that is capable of recognizing the content intention/meaning even with different HTML - which is not simple nor quick to write in any way.

Comment: The third option is sort of what I was going for. I figured that someone has thought about this problem before and might have solved it. Ideally they would have posted the source online or described the techniques they used.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But Google, for example, does that to detect a lot of stuff and relevance. I don't know if they have any open-source project related to that, but I doubt it. Hopefully someone else here knows of something like that.